# how to use for-loop to sum first n integer fractions

Tags: python

How to create a program that uses a for-loop to sum the first n
integer fractions 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + .... (n-1) / n + n / (n + 1). (n> 0 is a positive
integer and the last number in the sum is n / (n + 1)

I have tried many times but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Remember that Stackoverflow community helps you, but does not do the work for you. It is highly recommended that you include the code of your tries. Then it is likely that people helps you.

Comment: With what exactly are you struggling? Do you know how to make loops? Do you know how to add numbers? Please add your attempt so we can help with the real problem you have. Stack Overflow is not meant as a code-writing service where you get solutions for your problems (homework?)

Answer (score 1):

```py
n = int(input("Enter the nth term"))

fsum = 0
#Recommended to not use 'sum' itself 
#as it can cause problems with python's built in function which also has the same name

for i in range(1, n+1):
    fsum += i/(i+1)

print(fsum)
```

I guess this should solve your problem

If u want to know more about range function,see this
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Note that the range function only returns till the `stop` value and not including the `stop` value.The `stop` value in your case is the variable `n`.That is why we have to use `n+1` in the range function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```py
def sum_fraction(n):
    
    # Initialize the sum variable
    sum = 0
    
    # For loop : start from 1 ( n greater than zero ) : end with n
    for i in range(1, n):
        
        # Sum current term with all previous term (term by term)
        sum += i / (i + 1)
        
    return sum
        
n = 5
res = sum_fraction(n)
```